# How to get shared_ptr of derived type when object is created as base class?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, shared-ptr

I am trying to write an nodegraph library that can be re-used to implement several concrete different nodegraph types within a single application.  I have base classes Node and Port.  A Port is created on demand when requested by a Node.

I would like to be able to create subclasses MyNode and MyPort that can specialize and add functionality to Node and Port, but still inherit all the base features.

The problem I am specifically hitting is that i am using std::make_shared inside the Node class to create the Port object, but then in a MyNode object I would like that Port object to be cast to a MyPort object.

I'm including code below to try and demonstrate concretely the problem I am hitting right now, but I am wondering if perhaps my inheritance approach just isn't the right road to try going down, so I am very open to alternate ideas on how to structure my base/specialized nodegraph libraries.

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Port {
public:
    Port(string name) : m_name(name)   {}
    virtual ~Port() {}
    string getName()   {   return m_name; }
private:
    string m_name;
};

class Node {
public:
    shared_ptr<Port> getPort(string portName)
    {
        return make_shared<Port>(portName);
    }
};

class MyPort : public Port {
public:
    MyPort(string name) : Port(name) {}
    virtual ~MyPort() {}
    string getLongName()   {   return getName()+"_LONG";  }
};

class MyNode : public Node {
public:
    shared_ptr<MyPort> getPort(string portName)
    {
        shared_ptr<Port> tmpPort = Node::getPort(portName);
        return dynamic_pointer_cast<MyPort>(tmpPort);
    }
};

int
main (int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    MyNode node;
    shared_ptr<MyPort> port = node.getPort("Taco");

    if (port == nullptr) {
        cout << "null ptr" << std::endl;
    } else {
        cout << port->getName() << endl;
        cout << port->getLongName() << endl;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

When I run this code the dynamic_pointer_cast returns a nullptr.

Comment: Casting doesn’t change the type of the underlying object. If you want to get a `MyPort` object you’ll need to create it right away. You may be able to do so using the Factory pattern. Personally I came to the conclusion that dealing efficiently with different graph representations effectively needs Generic Programming. Have a look at the Boost Graph Library to see how it can be done.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Actually casting in C++ does change the type of the object, BUT casting a `shared_ptr` doesn't change the type of the object it points to.

Comment: @immibis: under no condition does a cast in C++ change the type of the casted object! You may get a *different*, temporary object (when the cast target type happens to be a value type) but the type of the original object remains unchanged. Pointer or reference casts merely change the type of the entity the object is accessed through (returning a corresponding temporary object in case of a pointer cast). ... and `dynamic_cast` verifies if the object indeed matches (for the other casts you need to know that it is the case; if it is not you get undefined behavior).

Answer (score 2):

You can't get a shared_ptr of derived type to a base class object.

In order to get a shared_ptr of a certain type to a certain object, the object has to actually be of that type. But in this case it isn't. The object is a `Port` - it is not, and never will be, a `MyPort`.

You need to ensure a `MyPort` is created in the first place. One way you could do this is by adding a `createPort` function. `Node::createPort` would then create a new `Port` but you could override it in `MyNode` so it creates a `MyPort`. Or, you could override `getPort`.

Answer (score 0):

Just update defination of `MyNode::getPort` as below.

```
shared_ptr<MyPort> getPort(string portName)
{
    return make_shared<MyPort>(portName);
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/B5r5uX7xETXpgq4Q)